# How long does it typically take before the AMP Status report in Search Console is available?

Tags: amp-html

I pushed a quick implementation of Accelerated Mobile Pages on a fairly large website yesterday, and am very eager to start seeing the AMP reports i Google Search Console.

How long would it typically take before they start showing up?

Or; how long did it take before *your* AMP reports became available?

Comment: John Mueller from Google said that the reports in Search Console aren't immediate and they can take a few days to update. This is why you wouldn't see a change there right after making an AMP page. You can read it in this [thread](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-amp-reports-in-google-search-console-are-delayed-21564.html).

Comment: Thanks, and true - nothing in Search Console is realtime ;-). My first reports showed up yesterday, btw. Think in total it took about three days before the first reports showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Took me 3 to 4 days.
I made some changes yesterday as I had some validation errors and, although my pages appears now in g.co/ampdemo, I see no changes in the search console. I think there's a 3 days delay in there

Comment: Is there any particular trick you're using to see your own pages back on the ampdemo page?

Comment: just the usual "site:mydomain.com somequery" you would use in the regular version of google.com

Comment: Odd enough, that doesn't work for me.. oh well, I managed to just Google my way over to some articles.

Answer (score 0):

if you are worried about 'will my page be finally valid? because I do not want to wait until the 2 or 3 days that google needs to test the page and end up with an error again...',

then you can test your URL online here : https://search.google.com/test/amp

If the result is valid, then the google search console result will not be far from it. Anyway if you still have an error from this link, then the google validator will not pass, you can be sure of it ;)